# Can I ignore the .env file when publishing eas update

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

According to the docs, the local .env file is evaluated when you run `eas update`.

> When you run eas update, any .env files present will be evaluated when your JavaScript is bundled. Any EXPO_PUBLIC_ variables in your application code will be replaced inline with the corresponding values from your .env files that are present on the machine from which the update is published, whether that is your local machine or your CI/ CD server.
> (https://docs.expo.dev/eas-update/environment-variables/)

Is there a way to ignore the local .env file when running `eas update`?